# SQL Server extract data from XML column without tag names

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, nodes

I have an XML string:

```
<XML>
 <xml_line>
   <col1>1</col1>
   <col2>foo 1</col2>
 </xml_line>
 <xml_line>
   <col1>2</col1>
   <col2>foo 2</col2>
 </xml_line>    
</XML>
```

I am extracting data from that string (stored in `@data_xml`) by storing it in SQL Server table and parsing it:

```
-- create temp table, insert XML string 
CREATE TABLE table1 (data_xml XML)

INSERT table1 
    SELECT @data_xml

-- parse XML string into temp table
SELECT
    N.C.value('col1[1]', 'int') col1_name,
    N.C.value('col2[1]', 'varchar(31)') col2_name,
FROM 
    table1
CROSS APPLY 
    data_xml.nodes('//xml_line') N(C)
```

I would like to know if there is a generic way to accomplish the same without specifying column names (i.e. col1[1], col2[1])

Comment: SQL Server is declarative by design.  Dynamic columns would require Dynamic SQL

Comment: Just to add to my comment, you can hash XML and create a hierarchy.  This is probably more than what you are looking for, but it can be trimmed down.   https://dbfiddle.uk/sE36tDoK

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks. I saw approach here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755806/select-all-xml-nodes-from-xml-column. That i can work with. Seems similar to yours. But was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: Shnugo is the king of XML (honestly huge fan).  That approach is a scaled down version of my function.  You may also note that it does not support attributes or complex structures.   Also I need to point out that both solutions, the columns are not dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
SELECT
    N.C.value('let $i := . return count(//xml_line[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') as LineNumber,
    Item.Node.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') name,
    Item.Node.value('.', 'varchar(max)') value
FROM 
    table1
CROSS APPLY 
    data_xml.nodes('//xml_line') N(C)
CROSS APPLY 
    N.C.nodes('*') Item(Node)
```

To get:

| LineNumber | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | col1 | 1 |
| 1 | col2 | foo 1 |
| 2 | col1 | 2 |
| 2 | col2 | foo 2 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O1msw6dv).

However, to spread columns horizontally, you will need to generate dynamic SQL after querying for distinct element names.

ADDENDUM: Here is an [updated db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PJh2_wth) that also shows a dynamic SQL example.

The above maps all values as `VARCHAR(MAX)`. If you have `NVARCHAR` data you can make the appropriate changes. If you have a need to map specific columns to specific types, you will need to explicitly define and populate a name-to-type mapping table and incorporate that into the dynamic SQL logic. The same may be necessary if you prefer that the result columns be in a specific order.

ADDENDUM 2: This [updated db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FPiUmI5T) now includes column type and ordering logic.

```
--------------------------------------------------
-- Extract column names
--------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @Names TABLE (name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT @Names   
SELECT DISTINCT Item.Node.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)')
FROM table1
CROSS APPLY data_xml.nodes('//xml_line/*') Item(Node)

--SELECT * FROM @Names

--------------------------------------------------
-- Define column-to-type mapping
--------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @ColumnTypeMap TABLE ( ColumnName SYSNAME, ColumnType SYSNAME, ColumnOrder INT)
INSERT @ColumnTypeMap
VALUES
    ('col1', 'int', 1),
    ('col2', 'varchar(10)', 2)

DECLARE @ColumnTypeDefault SYSNAME = 'varchar(max)'

--------------------------------------------------
-- Define SQL Templates
--------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @SelectItemTemplate VARCHAR(MAX) =
'    , N.C.value(<colpath>, <coltype>) <colname>
'

DECLARE @SqlTemplate VARCHAR(MAX) =
'SELECT
    N.C.value(''let $i := . return count(//xml_line[. << $i]) + 1'', ''int'') as LineNumber
<SelectItems>
FROM 
    table1
CROSS APPLY 
    data_xml.nodes(''//xml_line'') N(C)
'

--------------------------------------------------
-- Expand SQL templates into SQL
--------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @SelectItems VARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(SI.SelectItem, '')
              WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ISNULL(T.ColumnOrder, 999), N.Name)
    FROM @Names N
    LEFT JOIN @ColumnTypeMap T ON T.ColumnName = N.name
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT SelectItem = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            @SelectItemTemplate
            , '<colpath>', QUOTENAME(N.name + '[1]', ''''))
            , '<colname>', QUOTENAME(N.name))
            , '<coltype>', QUOTENAME(ISNULL(T.ColumnType, @ColumnTypeDefault), ''''))
    ) SI(SelectItem)
)

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE(@SqlTemplate, '<SelectItems>', @SelectItems)

--------------------------------------------------
-- Execute
--------------------------------------------------

SELECT DynamicSql = @Sql

EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result (with some additional data):

| LineNumber | col1 | col2 | bar | foo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | foo 1 | null | More |
| 2 | 2 | foo 2 | Stuff | null |

Comment: I've updated the above to include a fiddle that includes a dynamic SQL example.